# Can't catch exception for an invalid image URL in discord.py

Tags: python, exception, bots, discord.py

I have made an `embed_test` command in discord.py for my Discord bot, and I'm trying to make the bot say "invalid url" using a try ... except clause if the given image URL is invalid:

[image: embed_test command]

```py
@commands.command()
async def embed_test(sefl, ctx, *, image_url):

    embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Very nice title', description = 'Interesting description', color = 0x00A900)

    if (image_url[0], image_url[-1]) == ('"', '"'):

        try: embed.set_image(url = image_url[1:])

        except Exception: await ctx.send('invalid image url')

    else: await ctx.send('please enter the url in "quotation marks"')

    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

This works very well when the clause is not in an if ... else statement, but, as shown in the picture, I also want to make sure the user enters their URL in quotation marks. The problem is that when I run the command with an invalid URL in quotation marks, I get:

```
Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 BAD REQUEST (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.image.url: Not a well formed URL.
```

in my console even though I'm trying to catch the exception in my program.

Comment: You should really add the code here instead of a png link. That way people can try out the snip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're including the closing quotation mark with `image_url[1:]`.
You should use something like `image_url[1:-1]` instead.

The reason your error handling isn't working is because setting the image URL isn't when it's erroring. discord.py itself doesn't check the URL. As the full traceback should have pointed out to you, this error is occurring when you attempt to send the embed. It's sent to Discord's API and the request responds with an error code when Discord attempts to use that URL.

Also, you should try to avoid catching all exceptions rather than the specific exception that you're handling. Otherwise, you could mask other exceptions and make it more difficult to debug your code.
See https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions and https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html for more details about avoiding the bad practice of this type of error handling.